# How to apply multiple - email accounts to single Stack Overflow account

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I have 3 regular gmail accounts. I may be logged in to any of it, but when ever I try to log in to Stack Overflow - It just follows single account.

I have tried Gravatar for that. I have added all my email id's & photos to my gravatar account.

However, to log in to my Stack Overflow account, I must have to logged in to specific account which is associated with stackoverflow.com.

What should be the solution for this?

Comment: This is an old question. It is now possible to add *multiple* login methods to one account, not just two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a different openid provider as your secondary openid provider.

Log into these sites using this openid provider rather than your google accounts.

Then SO won't even care what google account you're logged on to at any given time.

Answer (score 23):

Click your profile pic in the top right corner.

> Edit profile & Settings tab -> My Logins -> Add more logins -> Google

Now select your second email id

Comment: should be selected answer

Comment: I wanted to add a second Google account, so for this to work my browser had to be signed in in both the account I was already signing in to stack exchange with and with the additional account I was trying to add, otherwise it failed silently

Answer (score 0):

You can associate an alternative openid with your account, so that gives you a 66%+ chance of being logged in. Beyond that... decide who you want to be?